# Merging Two Array String Objects - Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to "concatenate" or "merge" two column lists, but am finding an error below. It appears it does not like duplicates maybe. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('BCDE'))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('CDEF'))
inclusive_list13 = np.intersect1d(df1.columns, df3.columns)
inclusive_list23 = np.intersect1d(df2.columns, df3.columns)

inclusive_list13
Out[3]: array(['C', 'D'], dtype=object)

inclusive_list23
Out[4]: array(['C', 'D', 'E'], dtype=object)

inclusive_list = inclusive_list13 + inclusive_list23

inclusive_list
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (3,)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
inclusive_list = list(inclusive_list13) + list(inclusive_list23)
inclusive_list
```

Output:

```
['C', 'D', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```